# React Hook "useAuth0" cannot be called at the top level

Tags: reactjs, auth0

I'm trying to implement **Auth0** into my **React** project using this tutorial: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/react/02-calling-an-api.

Since I don't want to pass the **access token** on every page, I'm using a global file which I try to use on every Axios API call.

Code (api.js):

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react';

const {getAccessTokenSilently} = useAuth0();

const token = await getAccessTokenSilently();

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: `http://localhost:8080/`,
    headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`},
    timeout: 2000
});
```

I receive the following error:

```
Line 4:34:  React Hook "useAuth0" cannot be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
```

Example call in 'AssignmentSlice.js' (using Redux):

```
    api.post(`assignment/add`, initialAssignment)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data);
            return res.data;
        }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err.response);
        return err.response;
    })
```

What would be the best way/pattern to implement the Auth0 access token?

Comment: Maybe by creating a [custom hook](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks) ?

Answer (score 0):

This mean you need to call `useAuth0` from [react component](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_components.asp#:%7E:text=Components%20are%20independent%20and%20reusable,will%20concentrate%20on%20Function%20components.) to get `token`. Then passing `token` to API layer and call API as normal

See example here: https://auth0.github.io/auth0-react/

Comment: But then I would have to fetch the token in all components, since my app needs authentication on every page. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: It's easy by doing follow this step: 1: Get token from a page, 2: Store token into `store` layer. Then you can use `token` anywhere you want. See about `store` https://redux.js.org/api/store